# How to setup libphonenumber-for-php?

Tags: php

So I need to use libphonenumber-for-PHP but I have read it but still doesn't understand it how to install it. Do I need Linux/ubuntu to run it or can it be run on a windows device?

There is also an example of it, first, I want to run that on my laptop so I can test it. I have downloaded the example and put it in the USBwebserver I have running on my windows machine but doesn't work, probably I am just stupid.

the example:https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-example
Source:https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Comment: It appears to be pure PHP (rather than a C extension) so it will run on any PHP installation meeting its version requirements. As with most modern PHP code libraries, you need to have a functioning `composer` (https://getcomposer.org/) and when composer is installed, from your PHP application's project directory, you need to run `composer require giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php` which will setup a composer.json for your project if it does not already exist, and retrieve the code.

Comment: But if your code didn't yet use compoesr, you are not finished. You still need to include its autoloader so that PHP finds all the libphoneumber classes. At the top of your script or highest include, `require_once '/path/to/your/project/vendor/autoload.php`. Then the code examples should be usable.

Comment: Using only the example code (not your own project), before it is functional, you will need to have composer installed and then run `composer install` for it to retrieve the libphonenumber library and whatever else it has specified in composer.json.

Comment: Thanks for the info!!